# Where can one find a food vacuum?

Tags: storage-method, storage

It is a big pain to get soup out of a crockpot and put it into a ziploc bag. I am looking for a food vacuum which would basically just suck up the soup and put it in the bag. Does this exist?

Comment: I'd probably prefer putting a ladle and perhaps a jug and a funnel into my dishwasher over dismantling and cleaning some kind of vacuum setup.

Comment: "food pump" mostly gives you industrial-oriented google results...

Comment: @rackandboneman haha, not quite

Comment: Well, "pump" would be the nearest term, given that "vacuum" usually refers to a cleaning device that is meant to suck up things to be disposed of as trash :)

Comment: There's your market gap :) Hint: A vacuum-cleaner-like design which has fan in the air path is best marketed as "puree and package". A design that cyclically evacuates a container and works with two valves would probably work best (a true vacuum pump will hate you for smoke, let alone soup!) - Do mind that soup will boil cold in a hard vacuum :)

Comment: You don't need a pump.  You just need a length of sufficiently long and wide, sterilized hose:  1. Place the vessel to be filled so it is lower than the vessel to empty  2. Submerge hose in liquid.  3. Plug one end of the hose, and move it to the vessel to fill, while the other end remains in the vessel to empty.  4. Unplug the end until the vessel is filled to desired amount (and maybe a bit earlier, so you don't make a mess).  5. Move the re-plugged end to the next vessel to fill.  6. repeat 4&5 'til done. ... also a good idea to have the vessel to fill in a larger vessel in case of spills.

Comment: And there are special hoses for filling bottles from carboys in brewing ... they have a plug w/ a spring, so it unplugs when you push it in the bottom of the bottle ... they'd work for broth, I would think ... but I suspect they'd have problems w/ chunks (but I've never used one)

Comment: so, a miniature wet vac?

Comment: Not a vacuum (so not an answer), but have you considered a [sludge pump](http://www.grindex.com/product_overview/50hz-pumps/sludge_pumps/solid)?

Comment: @wumpusD'00m thanks. Too industrial, I'm looking for a quick, cheap, and easy solution

Comment: The solutions until now seem to assume some kind of uniform soup. How chunky are your meals?

Comment: what if you siphoned your soup? simple, no equipment, effective, works for chunky soups..

Comment: What is it about the crockpot that makes it hard for you to transfer the soup ?

Comment: @Batman it is heavy and I might either miss the bag when I am pouring or drop the bag out of my hands

Comment: Why are you holding the bag rather than say, putting it a pot and clipping it to the sides of the pot with some clothespins or something and then filling the bag?

Comment: Why not just put the soup in a bowl?

Comment: The problem is you may miss the bag when pouring or drop the bag?  Is there a reason a (large) ladle will not serve to move the soup in smaller, more controllable amounts?  Even a larger plastic container can be used to dip the soup out, one handed, in managable amounts.  Or, as Batman said, you can clip the bag to a bowl or pot to keep it up and open while transferring the soup.

Answer (score 2):

You want "a quick, cheap, and easy solution" that moves food with vacuum:

[image: Big baster][image: Baster]

I suppose the other one would be a very large ziplock, and you'd just put it over the whole top of the crockpot and quickly invert. Much wasted space, comparatively expensive bags.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what a pain it would be to clean.   Any regular vacuum is not going to be sanitary.

Consider put the bag in small container and fold the top over the lip and use a small ladle.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm... actually a small wet/dry vac can have the capability to do something like that. I would not recommend doing this, but there might not be any other quick cheap and easy options.

Take something like a small 1 gallon vac such as this http://amzn.to/2tfkgB0 
Line the bucket with a gallon ziplock bag and you now have a means to vacuum soup into a ziplock bag or any other bag.

Comment: I really wouldn't suggest this. The plastic is not designed for food usage and can not be guaranteed to be safe.